# Absolute position relative to inline element

Tags: css

I'm trying to center a line of text in a div and place an SVG after the centered text, but I don't want the width of the SVG to be considered for centering purposes.
The simplest way to achieve this is to add an invisible SVG before the text, but this requires unnecessary duplication of the SVG.
It seems like I should be able to achieve this with absolute positioning, but the default position is ever so slightly off and setting top/bottom/left/right positions it relative to the body, not the text.

How can I achieve the positioning in the green example below without needing multiple SVG elements on the page?

```css
.parent {
  width: 150px;
  border: solid;
  text-align: center;
}
.correct {
  background: rgb(183, 225, 205);
}
.incorrect {
  background: rgb(244, 199, 195);
}
svg {
  height: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<span>Centered</span>
</div>

<div class="parent incorrect">
<span>Centered</span>
<svg viewBox="0 0 2 2">
<path d="M0.43 1.77L1.2 1 0.43 0.24 0.67 0l1 1-1 1z"></path>
</svg>
</div>

<div class="parent correct">
<svg viewBox="0 0 2 2" style="visibility: hidden">
<path d="M0.43 1.77L1.2 1 0.43 0.24 0.67 0l1 1-1 1z"></path>
</svg>
<span>Centered</span>
<svg viewBox="0 0 2 2">
<path d="M0.43 1.77L1.2 1 0.43 0.24 0.67 0l1 1-1 1z"></path>
</svg>
</div>

<div class="parent incorrect">
<span>Centered</span>
<svg viewBox="0 0 2 2" style="position: absolute">
<path d="M0.43 1.77L1.2 1 0.43 0.24 0.67 0l1 1-1 1z"></path>
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you don't want to use `position: absolute;` but, It's seems the only way to ignore the `svg`.

```css
.parent {
  width: 150px;
  border: solid;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  padding:5px;
}
.correct {
  background: rgb(183, 225, 205);
}
.incorrect {
  background: rgb(244, 199, 195);
}
svg {
  height: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  padding-top:7px;
  padding-left:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent incorrect">
    <span>Centered</span>
</div>

<div class="parent correct">
    <span>Centered</span>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 2 2">
        <path d="M0.43 1.77L1.2 1 0.43 0.24 0.67 0l1 1-1 1z"></path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for. I was struggling to get absolute positioning to work because I forgot to put a relative position on the parent.

Answer (score 2):

You might set a negative `margin-right` or even use `svg` as a `span:after` background. See last two examples:

```css
.parent {
  width: 150px;
  border: solid;
  text-align: center;
}

.correct {
  background: rgb(183, 225, 205);
}

.incorrect {
  background: rgb(244, 199, 195);
}

svg {
  height: 12px;
}

.bg span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.bg span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: -15px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%202%202%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M0.43%201.77L1.2%201%200.43%200.24%200.67%200l1%201-1%201z%22%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E) no-repeat 50% 50% / 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span>Centered</span>
</div>

<div class="parent incorrect">
  <span>Centered</span>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 2 2">
<path d="M0.43 1.77L1.2 1 0.43 0.24 0.67 0l1 1-1 1z"></path>
</svg>
</div>

<div class="parent correct">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 2 2" style="visibility: hidden">
<path d="M0.43 1.77L1.2 1 0.43 0.24 0.67 0l1 1-1 1z"></path>
</svg>
  <span>Centered</span>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 2 2">
<path d="M0.43 1.77L1.2 1 0.43 0.24 0.67 0l1 1-1 1z"></path>
</svg>
</div>

<div class="parent margin correct">
  <span>Centered</span>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 2 2" style="margin-right:-14px">
<path d="M0.43 1.77L1.2 1 0.43 0.24 0.67 0l1 1-1 1z"></path>
</svg>
</div>

<div class="parent bg correct">
  <span>Centered</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I really like the simplicity of the `margin-right` approach, especially since the SVG is a known width.